# how to include css and js in default.ctp in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.2

echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

```
    echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
    echo $this->Html->css('style_variation');
    echo $this->Html->css('style');
    echo $this->Html->css('suggest');
    echo $this->Html->css('jquery.lightbox-0.5');
    echo $javascript->link('jquery.js');
    echo $javascript->link('jquery.lightbox-0.5.js');
    echo $javascript->link('suggest.js');
```

i am using this code but this is not working.

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms

Answer (score 1):

Include css with

```
echo $this->Html->css('example');
```

and javascript with

```
echo $this->Html->script('example');
```

Do not write the .js extension when including javascript.